# Getting the count of a constrained, joined query in Laravel's query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, count, eloquent

I have a one-to-one relationship between `users` and `activities`, such that each user has a `last_activity_id` which maps to a particular row in `activities`.

I need to be able to filter a list of users based on the value of a column in their last activity.  To be able to do additional things like pagination, this must be done in the query itself, so I cannot fetch the results and then apply the filters after the fact.  Thus, I use a `select` along with a `leftJoin` to bring the related columns directly into my result set:

```
$query = User::select(
            'users.*',
            'activities.description as last_activity_description')
         ->leftJoin('activities', 'activities.id', '=', 'users.last_activity_id')
         ->having('last_activity_description', 'like', "%blanchin%");
```

This seems to work fine, and I can call `$query->get()` to get the filtered result set.  It generates a query that looks like:

```
select `users`.*, 
    `activities`.`description` as `last_activity_description` 
from `users` 
left join `activities` on `activities`.`id` = `users`.`last_activity_id`
having `last_activity_description` like '%blanchin%'
```

However, if I try to then get a *count* on this result set by calling `$query->count()`, Laravel generates this (failed) query:

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `users` 
left join `activities` on `activities`.`id` = `users`.`last_activity_id` 
having `last_activity_description` like '%blanchin%'
```

It seems that calling `count()` has stripped out my original `select` clause and replaced it with `select count(*) as aggregate`, which means that my `having` clause fails because the `last_activity_description` alias is no longer defined.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the workaround is to not use the alias in my constraint, and simply use the actual table and column name instead.  This works just fine:

```
$query = User::select(
            'users.*',
            'activities.description as last_activity_description')
         ->leftJoin('activities', 'activities.id', '=', 'users.last_activity_id')
         ->where('activities.description', 'like', "%blanchin%")
         ->count();
```

Note also, that the `having` clause needs to be changed to a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the relation constraint and paginate?

```
User::whereHas('activities', function($query) use ($description) {
    return $query->where('description', 'LIKE', "%$description%");
})->paginate($results);
```

If you want to return the activity description too then:

```
User::whereHas('activities', function($query) use ($description) {
    return $query->where('description', 'LIKE', "%$description%");
})->with(['activities' => function($query) use ($description) {
    return $query->select('id', 'description as last_activity_description')
        ->where('description', 'LIKE', "%$description%");
}])->paginate($results);
```

**UPDATE**

The above works with the `activities()` relation defined on your user model:

```
public function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Activity::class, 'last_activity_id');
}
```

Comment: Even with this, I still need the `leftJoin` to constrain based on the `last_activity_id`.

Comment: Not if you defined the `activities()` relation on your User model.  Laravel's relationship will do that for you. I updated my answer to show that.